# Найти длину подпоследовательности с максимальным количеством равных элементов

Tags: c++

Задача такова.

> Имеется отсортированный массив из чисел, каждое из которых `є N, < 10^9`. Сначала считывается длина заданного массива (`< 10^5`), потом из стандартного ввода считывается сам массив. Требуется найти длину подпоследовательности, состоящую только из одинаковых элементов, если таких подпоследовательностей несколько, вывести максимальную из длин. Кроме того, если ответ `< 3`, вывести `0`.
>
> **К примеру :**
>
> *input :* `4 5 5 5 1000`
>
> *output :* `3`

Имеется также кусок кода:

```
int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie();
    cout.tie();

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int sticks[n];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> sticks[i];

    int prev = sticks[0];
    int range = 1;
    int answer = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (sticks[i] != prev)
        {
            answer = max(answer, range);
            range = 1;
        }
        else
            ++range;
        prev = sticks[i];
    }

    answer = max(answer, range);

    cout << (answer < 3 ? 0 : answer);

    return 0;
}
```

При запуске на фин.тестах, проходит только на 20 баллов из 100. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за ошибка?

Comment: cin >> n;    int sticks[n];
При этом в условии ничего не сказано о необходимости считывания длины...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, исправил условие.

Comment: 3 5 5 5 1000 - расскажите-ка, как тут длина равна трем?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, черт, я печатать не умею xD

Comment: А что выдаст для 4 1 1 2 2?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, код? Код выдает 0

Comment: Что код? 0 он вам выведет, потому что либо алгоритм кривой, либо условие неполное.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, "Кроме того, если длина < 3, вывести 0"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68042/discussion-between---and-niklex).

Comment: Если чисел условно "много", то `int sticks[n];` может переполнить стек. Потом, как отмечает @ВладимирМартьянов, то, что массив отсортированный - вероятно, не имеет отношения к задаче.

Comment: @Niklex длина ЧЕГО меньше трех? У меня явно указана длина 4.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov если чисел достаточно много, ОС может не дать выделить такой объем. В целом, задача решается без выделения памяти вообще на конечном автомате

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, длина ответа. Если макс длина такой подпоследовательности меньше, чем 3., надо вывести 0. Хотя даже без этого условия алгоритм не меняется...

Comment: А теперь внимательно прочитайте условия еще раз и сравните с тем, как вы их поняли. Две правки в условиях задачи наводят на мысли...

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, по условию не больше 10 в 5

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, исправления были только по поводу входных данных. Сути задачи не меняет

Comment: @Niklex Третье исправление условия :-D

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я просто алгоритм уже три раза пересмотрел, и меня напрягает то, что задача достаточно простая, алгоритм похож на правильный (штук 15 тестов придумал разных), а заходить не хочет на двух разных незаввисимых системах..

Comment: @Niklex сравнивайте ваше понимание задачи и условия. Три правки(!) в условиях говорят о том, что вы неверно условия понимаете

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, вы правы, в корне не верно понимал условие xD. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы найти наибольшее количество одинаковых смежных чисел в отсортированной входной последовательности, удобно [`groupby()` функциональнось](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) использовать. На Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from itertools import groupby

numbers = (n for line in sys.stdin for n in map(int, line.split()))
next(numbers) # skip size
max_same_count = max(sum(1 for _ in same) for _, same in groupby(numbers))
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/YmSAcj).

На C++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  using U = unsigned long; // <10**9
  std::istream_iterator<U> it {std::cin}, eof; // read natural numbers
  if (it == eof)
    return 1; // invalid input, no size

  U count = 0, max_same_count = count; // <10**5
  U last = -1;
  for (++it /* skip size */; it != eof; ++it) {
    if (count && last == *it) {
      ++count;
    } else {
      max_same_count = std::max(max_same_count, count);
      count = 1;
      last = *it;
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::max(max_same_count, count) << '\n';
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/ft43x6).

Часть *«если ответ < 3, вывести 0»* самостоятельно добавьте.

Answer (score 0):

Так проще, лишнее присваивание и скобки на любителя.
`

```
int prev = sticks[0];
int range = 1;
int answer = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    if (sticks[i] != prev)
    { 
        prev = sticks[i];
        answer = max(answer, range);
        range = 1;
    }
    else
        ++range;
answer = max(answer, range);
```

`